# EPPlus two color conditional date format

Tags: epplus

I have a column with dates and I want to conditionally color any cell that is older that 2 week yellow, and any that is older than 90 days red.  I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: Well, can you share any thing that you have tried? How will you address the columns?Any code snippets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be able to just add the conditions like any other.  You can use the `TODAY()` function in excel and subtract:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Conditional_Formatting_Date()
{
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56741642/epplus-two-color-conditional-date-format
    var file = new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\Conditional_Formatting_Date.xlsx");
    if (file.Exists)
        file.Delete();

    //Throw in some data
    var dataTable = new DataTable("tblData");
    dataTable.Columns.AddRange(new[] {
        new DataColumn("Col1", typeof(DateTime)),
        new DataColumn("Col3", typeof(string))
    });

    var rnd = new Random();
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        var row = dataTable.NewRow();
        row[0] = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-rnd.Next(1, 100));
        row[1] = $"=TODAY() - A{i +1}";
        dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    //Create a test file    
    using (var package = new ExcelPackage(file))
    {
        //Make the stylesheet
        var ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("table");
        var range = ws.Cells[1, 1].LoadFromDataTable(dataTable, false);
        ws.Column(1).Style.Numberformat.Format = "mm-dd-yy";
        ws.Column(1).AutoFit();

        //Add the calc check
        var count = 0;
        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
            ws.Cells[++count, 2].Formula = row[1].ToString();

        //Add the conditions - order matters
        var rangeA = range.Offset(0, 0, count, 1);

        var condition90 = ws.ConditionalFormatting.AddExpression(rangeA);
        condition90.Style.Font.Color.Color = Color.White;
        condition90.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
        condition90.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Color = Color.Red;
        condition90.Formula = "TODAY() - A1> 90";
        condition90.StopIfTrue = true;

        var condition14 = ws.ConditionalFormatting.AddExpression(rangeA);
        condition14.Style.Font.Color.Color = Color.Black;
        condition14.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
        condition14.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Color = Color.Yellow;
        condition14.Formula = "TODAY() - A1> 14";

        package.Save();
    }
}
```

Which gives this in the output:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming that you have the column number of the date column and number of rows in your records. Also, the following loop is under assumption that the first row is your column header and records begin from second row. Change the loop counter's initialization and assignment accordingly.

```
 int rowsCount; //get your no of rows
            int dateColNumber; //Assign column number in excel file of your date column
            string cellValue;
            DateTime dateValue;
            DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
            double daysCount;

            for(int i=1;i<rowsCount;i++)
            {
                cellValue = ws.Cells[i + 1, dateColNumber].Text.ToString(); //First row is header start from second
                if(DateTime.TryParse(cellValue,out dateValue))
                {
                    daysCount = (today - dateValue).Days;
                    if(daysCount>90)
                    {
                        ws.Cells[i + 1,dateColNumber].Style.Fill.PatternType = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                        ws.Cells[i + 1,dateColNumber].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
                    }
                    else if(daysCount>14)
                    {
                        ws.Cells[i + 1, dateColNumber].Style.Fill.PatternType = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                        ws.Cells[i + 1, dateColNumber].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow);
                    }

                }
            }
```

Comment: This is hardcoding a color into the cell. It’s not using conditional formatting.